# help needed with pdftex [solved]

Tags: pdftex, indexing

i'm trying to build a pdf out of this file: https://github.com/stuartcarnie/vice-emu/blob/master/vice/doc/vice.texi

i downloaded miktex-portable-2.9.6236.exe from https://miktex.org/download

so, basically i just fired up `pdftex vice.texi` and got a vice.pdf (along with other vice.* files).

the problem is, there is no index at the end, all it says is "(Index is nonexistent)".

what is missing?

Comment: You should compile twice, most likely

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Have you looked at something like https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing that walks through how to make an index?  There are several steps you need to do.  If that still won't work, make the smallest .tex file you can that you think should have an index but doesn't, and post that here (not behind a link).  Also post the commands you're using.

Comment: Please, instead of marking your answer as [solved] consider accepting a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have usable texi2pdf, try

```
pdftex vice.texi
pdftex vice.texi
texindex vice.??
pdftex vice.texi
```

Comment: that works! i had to download texinfo-4.13a-setup.exe to get a working texinfo. i guess the other postings would work, too. but in windows the shell scripts don't work well.

Answer (score 3):

The file is a `texinfo` file, so you should compile it with the script `texi2pdf`, that takes care of multiple runs for cross references and for the indices.